# The flat module, module is not flat

Tags: modules, flatness

Why $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Q}$ is flat and $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not flat?
P/s: How can I prove them by definition and without functor. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb Z$-modules are flat iff they are torsion-free. Hence $\Bbb Q$ is flat, but $\Bbb Z/n$ is not.

References:

[Show that a Z-module A is flat if and only if it is torsion free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686561/show-that-a-z-module-a-is-flat-if-and-only-if-it-is-torsion-free)