# is $R/I$ flat over $S$ if $R/\sqrt{I}$ is flat over $S$ and $I$ is primary?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, flatness

Let $R$ be an $S$-algebra and let $I$ be a primary ideal such that $R/\sqrt{I}$ is flat over $S$ where $\sqrt{I}$ is the radical of $I$. Is $R/I$ flat over $S$? I don't mind assuming $R,S$ Noetherian, and even regular.

(as a reason for why one might be interested in this question, consider an ideal $J \subset B$ and let $I$ be the unique primary ideal in a primary decomposition  corresponding to a minimal associated prime of $J$. In this case $I$ endows the corresponding irreducible component $Z=V(I)$ of $X=\mathrm{Spec} B/J$ with canonical scheme structure. The statement above says that if $Z_{red}$ is flat over $Y=\mathrm{Spec} A$, then $Z$ itself is flat over $Y$)

Comment: Not sure. Though the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686561/show-that-a-z-module-a-is-flat-if-and-only-if-it-is-torsion-free might be a good start. You need to find some ideal in $R/I$ which is not in $R/ \sqrt{I}$ for which the map in $(iii)$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: here is the reposting of the question on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373407/flatness-and-reduction